# How can I convert a timezone to a users' local TZ while respecting DST changes that may occur in either the local or remote TZ?

Tags: php, timezone

I've been tasked with displaying a date for an event in the local TZ. The date to represent is in the future and it may run across DST changes on either the local or event TZ.

My boss says it isn't good enough to simple convert the event time to local as Friday @ 8pm is not accurate if DST changes for one of the TZs involved.

I'm almost convinced that this is a non-starter for what we need the output information for, but he maintains that he wants it done.

Has anyone a good source and easy method to do these calculations? Bear in mind that this is for dates on a website and potentially this will need to be done on a significant number of pages...

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718935/how-do-i-get-a-visitors-time-zone-in-php

Answer (score 0):

1. Gather the local time zone from the user.  You may want to have them expressly pick a zone instead of guessing for them.  There are some areas that have *very* nonstandard DST use.
2. Store *every* datetime in UTC.  Every last one of them.
3. Make sure your database either does not understand timezones and thus does not manipulate datetime fields, or that it *does* understand timezones and you expressly set storage of datetimes to be in UTC.  MySQL has *horrible* timezone support, for example, while PostgreSQL lets you define the timezone with the datetime itself.  It's swanky.
4. Use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/class.datetime) class to represent datetimes, because then you can...
5. Use a [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/class.datetimezone) passed to a DateTime's [`setTimezone`](http://php.net/datetime.settimezone) method to simply change the UTC time into a local time as needed.
6. Display the local-correct DateTime to the user.
7. ???
8. Profit!

Comment: Does DateTime take into account DST changes between the two locations (local and where the event is...)? I think some determination has to happen beforehand to determine if there is an offset or not.

Comment: As long as the timezone database that PHP uses is up to date, then yes.  If you're on Linux, and are using the OS-native PHP, then you're probably OK.  If you're not on Linux, or you're using a PHP version that didn't ship with the OS, your timezone database may be out of date.  The older it is, the more likely that it's going to have incorrect transition dates for the US.  You can inspect these manually by calling [`getTransitions`](http://php.net/datetimezone.gettransitions).