# Fetching yesterday's mySQL data with visitor's Time Zone

Tags: php, mysql

I'm successfully fetching yesterday's mySQL data using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM  track
WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

However, it uses server's time zone. My server is located in US, If visitor is from a different timezone than US (ex:asia or europe) my yesterday data won't be correct for user. I want to fetch the correct yesterday results based on visitor's time zone. I can get the visitor timezone in php, but I can't figured out how to use it in mySQL.

Comment: try this link you will find what you want. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718935/how-do-i-get-a-visitors-time-zone-in-php

Comment: My problem is not about getting current timezone, but using it on mysql when fetching data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't store times as UNIX timestamp, but instead as [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html).  Then you can simply set [`time_zone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) and everything will be converted as you wish:

```sql
SET time_zone = '+10:00';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   track
WHERE  date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
   AND date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Otherwise, you can use [`CONVERT_TZ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   track
WHERE  date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, '+3:00', '+10:00'))
   AND date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '+3:00', '+10:00'))
```

Comment: I was just typing up a repionse to cover the same issues.  If you have any designs on querying against your data in MySQL, DON"T USE UNIX TIMESTAMPS.  The fact the you need to convert those timestamps to MySQL datetimes before you use them in queries means you will immediately disallow the use of indexes for query optimization.  The first query shown in this answer will be able to use an index on `date`, the second won't).  I was also going to state that you might simply want to use UTC as the basis for all date in the `date` field and leave you application to convert to local user time.

Comment: @MikeBrant: See my revised answer, where indexes can be used with the second query (using UNIX timestamps).

Comment: @eggyal Good update. Event though you can get around index problem in this case I would still recommend, as you did originally, to the OP to use datetime/timestamp field, as there are other time where you might want to do daily reports to other aggregations on the fields that would be difficult with unix timestamps

Comment: Why you have used +3:00 and +10:00 together ?

Comment: @user198989: To convert from the server time zone, e.g. `+3:00`, to user's time zone e.g. `+10:00`.